# How to use Wikipedia api in android

Tags: android, mediawiki

I'm developing an app to get Location name then put it into a googlemap and display that location wiki page . I tied to search but There is some phonegap android app .

My question is : Is there any Wiki API for android native app to get and search information ? and how to implement it ?

Comment: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did a Google search for wiki API and it brought me here:

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page

It is not specifically for android but it should be able to work for you.
An example:

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&titles=API&prop=revisions&rvprop=content

Comment: How can it work for me . It's respone an unmeaning content with a redirect *: "#REDIRECT [[Application programming interface]]{{R from abbreviation}}" :(

Comment: You make a request from an android app to the url with your own titles value and parse the data.

Answer (score 1):

If you can not find a usable api, you can use JSoup to parse wikipedia and return relevant information or you can build a url based on user's input and implement a webview